# need help in whatsapp text api

Tags: php, jquery

Assume the below php code has resulted in the following output: abc,xyz

```
 $deliverables = explode('-', $deliverable_type);
    foreach ($deliverables as $deliver){
      $deliver;                   
        $event_query = 'SELECT * FROM deliverable_types WHERE deliverable_code = {$deliver}';
        $select_event_query = mysqli_query($con,$event_query);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_event_query)){
        $deliverable_code = $row['deliverable_code'];
        $get_deliverable_name = $row['deliverable_name'];            
        echo $get_deliverable_name . ",";
      }  
      echo '<br>';
  }
```

Now when we click the below link, it displays only the last value i.e xyz..Is there any way to display all the values i.e abc,xyz

```
enter code here
<a class='wa-link btn btn-success' href='https://wa.me/919876543210?text=Hi Deliverable_Type:$get_deliverable_name'  target='_blank'>
  <i class='fab fa-whatsapp fa-lg'></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Start by properly URL-encoding the value of the parameter you are introducing into that URL, and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @CBRoe It doesn't fix the issue